# String length of a NULL

Tags: c, string, string-length

I was trying to find the string length of a `NULL` and `""`

when I tried `a=strlen("");` I got zero as output.
and when I tried `a=strlen(NULL);` I got core dump error.

What exactly happening in these two statements? Will memory allocate for `""`

Comment: If you call a str* C-string function on a non-C-string, that is a bad thing.  If you do bad things, it is likely that bad things will happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks why doing a bad thing can have bad consequences.

Comment: @MartinJames: Yes it does -- which IMHO makes it a perfectly valid question.

Comment: It also asks why `strlen("")` yields 0, which is also a perfectly valid question.  Nominated to reopen.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's akin to 'I drove my car into a tree, why am I in hospital?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal `""` is a null terminated string consisting of a length-one array with the null-termination character `'\0'`. `NULL`, on the other hand, is the null pointer, not a null-terminated string. It does not point to any valid location in memory, and it cannot be de-referenced.

`strlen` requires that its argument be a null terminated string, otherwise it yields *undefined behaviour* (UB). In this case, the UB is most likely caused by de-referencing the NULL pointer. The bottom line is that you can only pass a null-terminated string or all bets are off.

Comment: Good answer but you didn't really address the strlen(null) which isn't passing a empty string. Recommend adding why that does core dump.

Comment: @ydobonebi I thought it was implicit. I tried to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: On most systems, it attempts to dereference 0 and segfaults/AV's before it gets any chance to check for any terminator.

Comment: When you run strlen, you're asking it "Go to this address, count the number of non-zero bytes you find there, and return it.". A string like `""` is actually allocated physical memory, the first byte of which is a zero, so there are no non-zero bytes there, and it correctly reports 0. Try `printf("%p", "")`--it will print a real address. NULL is not a valid pointer to any object in memory, so strlen(NULL) has no meaning. What it actually does is up to the implementation. It might very well return a number, or crash, or do anything else.

Comment: @MartinJames Good point. I re-phrased the answer.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Agreed, the null-terminator is a bit of a red herring here. I re-phrased the answer.

Comment: There have been systems where memory address `0` appears to contain zero, so `strlen(NULL)` would actually yield `0`. That's the thing about undefined behavior; it can do *anything*. Quietly doing what you might expect is probably the worst possible consequence; it means you have a bug that's going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right. It could well have implicitly converted to `0`s. At the same time, de-referencing could still have caused a seg fault. Or not. UB is so much fun.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm not sure what implicit conversion you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of [strlen()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) states that,

```
size_t strlen( const char *str );
```

it will returns the length of the C string `str`. But

> The behavior is undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by `str`.

In

```
a=strlen(NULL);
```

`NULL` (*null pointer*, doesn't point to anything) don't have a *null character*, so you found undefined behavior.

Comment: No, the problem is that `NULL` doesn't point to a character array (and therefore is not a string).

Comment: That's not the only reason `NULL is not a string. Pointers are not strings. `str` is not a string; it's a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` give length of string till `'\0'` indicating string termination.

`NULL` is a null pointer. It’s a constant, defined in `stdio.h`.Thus `strlen` gives undefined behaviour.

Where as `""` is string containing `null character` thus `strlen` gives `0`.

Comment: @melpomene  Thank you ,I was not aware of that .

Comment: @melpomene: That's not correct. The standard explicitly says that `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>`, in `<stdio.h>`, and in several other headers. `<stdio.h>` does *not* `#include <stddef.h>`. For example, `#include <stdio.h>` does not make `offsetof` visible.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you, I was not aware of that. :-)